# want to make it responsive by resizing window( in tab view 2 image, in mobile 1 image)

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-top: 70px;
}

.column {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 24%;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.column img {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 4px 4px;
    align-items: center;
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    .column {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex: 48%;
        max-width: 48%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

In full screen view, I want to display 4 images;
in tab view, I want to display 2 images; and,
in mobile view, I want to display 1 image.

However, using flexbox, I am getting problem.
Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead,

```
    .column{
       display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-basis: 24%;
        max-width: 24%;
      }
    media only sreen and (max-width:768px){//ipad
     .column {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-basis: 48%;
        max-width: 48%;
      }
    }
    media only screen and (max-width:375px){//iphone
      .column {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-basis: 98%;
        max-width: 98%;
      } 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have errors in your CSS: `flex 1 1 100%;` is missing `:`.
But It still won't work the way you want.

You should use `flex: 25%` to make 4 images appear beside each other and `flex:50%` for the tablets for 2 images beside each other, and then you use padding to make the spaces between them. Except you are applying the `flex` to images that can't have padding so you have to use margins so you have to use a smaller flex value.

This code should work for you.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; 
  padding-top: 70px;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;  /* so images appear side by side */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column img {
  flex: 24%;     /* this makes 4 images line up in the row, (You usually use 25% and add space with padding) */
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%; 
  margin: 4px;/* ()you usually use padding, but because this is an image we can't */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  /* half width on tablet - small laptops */
  .column img {
    flex: 48%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  /* images stack on top of each other in a column */
  .column {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .column img{
    flex: 1;
    margin: 4px 0; /* the margin makes the images bigger than the column so remove the side margins */
  }
  }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x50" alt="">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x50" alt="">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x50" alt="">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x50" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x50" alt="">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x50" alt="">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x50" alt="">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x50" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x50" alt="">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x50" alt="">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x50" alt="">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x50" alt="">
  </div>

</div>
```